# How can I include version number in output file name?

Tags: microsoft-ajax-minifier, ajaxmin

I'm using XML Manifest File and I'd like to have the project build version concatenated in the output file name

e.g: library-1.0.0.js

Is it possible or any work around?

Comment: Still with no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [https://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/](https://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/%20msbuildextensionpack)

```
 <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Assembly TaskAction="GetInfo" NetAssembly="$(OutputPath)\xxx.dll" >
     <Output TaskParameter="OutputItems" ItemName="Info" />
     </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Assembly>
     <Message Text="Version: %(Info.AssemblyVersion)" Importance="high" />
```